# Does Facebook allow preloading a specific message from a user to a page?

Tags: facebook, webintents

I know that Facebook allows web intents of sharing URLs, along with the ability to select whether it goes into a message, or to your wall, but I was wondering if there is an ability to do something where a user can click a link/button, and it opens up a popup/page with a given "page", and a message pre-written.

There is no link to be shared, just a message, as if the user has wrote on the pages wall.

If there is functionality, but it requires specific things, such as the user must be subscribed to an app, or the page must be subscribed to the app, etc, then that can all be achieved.

My feeling is that it would be possibly open to abuse, though Twitter allows similar.

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is never allowed to prefill any message:

> Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the person can edit or remove the content before sharing.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/